# What is the Debian stance on systemd?

Tags: debian, systemd

Does Debian have a policy on systemd? Does every element of systemd get adopted? Do they have a statement of adherence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only [official Debian stance on systemd comes from *"General Resolution: Init systems and systemd"*](https://www.debian.org/vote/2019/vote_002). **This pertains only to the init system.** The resolution was "systemd but we support exploring alternatives". Voting closed on 2019-12-27, and I can't find a further statement pertaining to the rest of the systemd ecosystem. An important point here is that there was a more pro-systemd stance that was rejected which was *"focus on systemd"*.

You can see this decision described here,

> **Choice 2: B**: Systemd but we support exploring alternatives
> Using its power under Constitution section 4.1 (5), the project issues the following statement describing our current position on Init systems, multiple init systems, and the use of systemd facilities. This statement describes the position of the project at the time it is adopted. That position may evolve as time passes without the need to resort to future general resolutions. The GR process remains available if the project needs a decision and cannot come to a consensus.
>
> The Debian project recognizes that systemd service units are the preferred configuration for describing how to start a daemon/service. However, Debian remains an environment where developers and users can explore and develop alternate init systems and alternatives to systemd features. Those interested in exploring such alternatives need to provide the necessary development and packaging resources to do that work. Technologies such as elogind that facilitate exploring alternatives while running software that depends on some systemd interfaces remain important to Debian. It is important that the project support the efforts of developers working on such technologies where there is overlap between these technologies and the rest of the project, for example by reviewing patches and participating in discussions in a timely manner.
>
> Packages should include service units or init scripts to start daemons and services. Packages may use any systemd facility at the package maintainer's discretion, provided that this is consistent with other Policy requirements and the normal expectation that packages shouldn't depend on experimental or unsupported (in Debian) features of other packages. Packages may include support for alternate init systems besides systemd and may include alternatives for any systemd-specific interfaces they use. Maintainers use their normal procedures for deciding which patches to include.
>
> Debian is committed to working with derivatives that make different choices about init systems. As with all our interactions with downstreams, the relevant maintainers will work with the downstreams to figure out which changes it makes sense to fold into Debian and which changes remain purely in the derivative.